# How can I replace a named group's value

Tags: java, regex

I have the regex

```
private static final String COPY_NUMBER_REGEX = ".*copy(?<copy_num>\\d+)";
```

And I need to replace the named group as follows:

```
private void setCopyNum(){
    Pattern pa = Pattern.compile(COPY_NUMBER_REGEX);
    Matcher ma = pa.matcher(template.getName());
    if(ma.find()){
        Integer numToReplace = Integer.valueOf(ma.group("copy_num")) + 1;
        //How to replace the value of the original captured group with numToReplace?
    }
}
```

The question is in the comment in fact. Is there something in Java Regex that allows us to replace named groups value? I mean to get a new String with a replaced value, of course. For instance:

```
input: Happy birthday template - copy(1)
output: Happy birthday template - copy(2)
```

Comment: Yes. This can be done. Please Show us exact input and expected output.

Comment: @TheLostMind I've added an example of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty solution:

```
//                                 | preceded by "copy"
//                                 |       | named group "copynum":
//                                 |       |          | any 1+ digit
final String COPY_NUMBER_REGEX = "(?<=copy)(?<copynum>\\d+)";
// using String instead of your custom Template object
String template = "blah copy41";
Pattern pa = Pattern.compile(COPY_NUMBER_REGEX);
Matcher ma = pa.matcher(template);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
// iterating match
while (ma.find()) {
    Integer numToReplace = Integer.valueOf(ma.group("copynum")) + 1;
    ma.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(numToReplace));
}
ma.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Output**

```
blah copy42
```

**Notes**

- `copy_num` is an invalid named group - no underscores allowed
- The example is self-contained (would work in a main method). You'll need to adapt slightly to your context.
- You might need to add escaped parenthesis around your named group, if you need to actually match those: `"(?<=copy\\()(?<copynum>\\d+)(?=\\))"`